# finding the critical region of most powerful test

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, inference, statistical-power

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be from a density function $f(x;\theta)=3\theta x^2e^{-\theta x^3} ;x>0,\theta>0$.

From the Neyman-Pearson Lemma the most powerful test to test, $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ vs $H_1:\theta=\theta_1$ where $\theta_1>\theta_0$, 
is $\sum X_i^3<k$.

In the question it is asked to find the distribution of $X^3$ and show that it has a exponential distribution. **Question:** Is my method for doing so (below) correct?

**Approach:** I used inverse transform method. As $F(x)=1-e^{-\theta x^3}$, $X^3$ is distributed as:
$${\log(1-u)\over -\theta}\,,$$ where $U \sim \operatorname{Uniform}[0,1]$.

Is this correct? Is this exponentially distributed?

In order to find **k**, when $n=30$, $\theta_0=5$ at 1% level, I wrote the following R code. I generated a distribution for $\sum X_i^3$:

```
a<-function(theta,n,nsim){
    m<-c()
    for(i in 1:nsim){
    u<-runif(n)
    y<- log(1-u)/(-theta)
    x<- y^(1/3)
    z<-sum(x)
    m<-c(m,z)
    }

quantile(m,0.01)
}
a(5,30,10000)
```

and found $k$ to be $13.19248$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Double-check the power of $x$ in the exponent in your $f$ in the first line

Comment: @Glen_b I don't need `x<- y^(1/3)` right, since `y<- log(1-u)/(-theta)` gives the distribution of $X^3$. So just using `m<-c(m,y)` I get k to be 3.721134

Comment: ***please*** double-check you have correctly copied the power of x in the exponent in your f in the first line (I think it should not be 2).

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry. Corrected it. Can you please check if what I have done is correct